# Login is working properly but friend list is not shown and application crash due to null pointer exception

Tags: android, facebook

I'm new to facebook integaration, please help me with following issue:

null pointer exception at on click of the button of the alert box named as facebook

```
    private void onClickPickFriends() {
        final FriendPickerFragment fragment = new FriendPickerFragment();

        setFriendPickerListeners(fragment);

        showPickerFragment(fragment);
}

//
    private void showPickerFragment(PickerFragment<?> fragment) {
        fragment.setOnErrorListener(new PickerFragment.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
            public void onError(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment,
                    FacebookException error) {
                String text = getString(R.string.exception, error.getMessage());
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
                Log.e("error", error.getMessage());
        }
    });

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragContainer, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();

        controlsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // We want the fragment fully created so we can use it immediately.
        fm.executePendingTransactions();

        fragment.loadData(false);
}

    private void setFriendPickerListeners(final FriendPickerFragment fragment) {
        fragment.setOnDoneButtonClickedListener(new                              FriendPickerFragment.OnDoneButtonClickedListener() {
        @Override
             public void onDoneButtonClicked(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment) {
                onFriendPickerDone(fragment);
        }
    });
}

    private void onFriendPickerDone(FriendPickerFragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack();

    String results = "";

        List<GraphUser> selection = fragment.getSelection();
    tags = selection;
    if (selection != null && selection.size() > 0) {
            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (GraphUser user : selection) {
                names.add(user.getName());
        }
            results = TextUtils.join(", ", names);
    } else {
            results = getString(R.string.no_friends_selected);
    }

        showAlert(getString(R.string.you_picked), results);
}

    private void showAlert(String title, String message) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(title).setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(R.strin`enter code here`g.ok, null).show();
}
```

code of the button click:

```
build.setNegativeButton("Facebook",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {





onClickPickFriends();

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot fetch friend list directly.For this you have to submit your app to facebook and if the approve then only you will be able to fetch friend list.

Below mentioned link provide you changes & available features while moving facebook v1.0 to v2.0.

Reference link :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Read it very carefully. They have given all the points in it.

Comment: i submitted my app on developer.facebook.com  and extend the permission to read friendslist

Comment: controlsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE); error is at this line thta null pointer exception

Comment: yes i tried but after this this will give an exception of "an active access token must be used to query information about the current user "...